# css mask-image not working

Tags: css

Any idea on why the flag isn't filling the h2 text below? Dev url: http://runnerupapparel.com/building/ (info panel)

The background url is linking correctly: http://runnerupapparel.com/building/images/usa.png

```
h2.usa {
  background-size: 100px auto;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(../images/usa.png);
  -o-mask-image: url(../images/usa.png);
  -moz-mask-image: url(../images/usa.png);
 -ms-mask-image: url(../images/usa.png);
 mask-image: url(../images/usa.png);
 letter-spacing: -2px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the effect you are trying to achieve?

The image you are using is 100% opaque throughout. The `mask-image` is only beneficial when the png image used has different transparency parts. It essentially applies the transparency properties of the png image to whatever you are using it on.

For a better example of what I mean: http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/11/01/css3-text-effects-with-webkit-masking/

I have taken your image, desaturated it, and quickly removed all the areas that are white (made them transparent). Replace your `mask-image` URL with the one that I edited and you can see the difference: http://i49.tinypic.com/xe278p.png

It is also worth noting that at this time, `mask-image` only works with webkit browsers (ex. Chrome).